# Let $S$ be the set of all points $z$ in the complex plane such that ${\left(1+\frac{1}z \right) }^4=1$. Then, the points of $S$ are -

Tags: complex-numbers, solution-verification, complex-geometry

> **QUESTION:** Let $S$ be the set of all points $z$ in the complex plane such that
> $${\left(1+\frac{1}z \right) }^4=1$$
> Then, the points of $S$ are (choose the correct option)
> (A) vertices of a rectangle
>
> (B) vertices of a right-angled triangle
>
> (C) vertices of an equilateral triangle
>
> (D) collinear
>
> Source: [ISI B-MATH UGA 2017](https://www.isical.ac.in/%7Eadmission/IsiAdmission2017/PreviousQuestion/BStat-BMath-UGA-2017.pdf)

---

**MY ANSWER:** If we consider $z=x+iy$ then we can write the given equation as $${\left( \frac{(x+1)+iy}{x+iy} \right) }^4=1$$ $$\implies { \left(\frac{\big((x+1)+iy\big)(x-iy)}{x^2+y^2} \right) }^4=1$$ $$\implies { \left( \frac{x^2+y^2+x-iy}{x^2+y^2} \right) }^4=1$$ Now, I don't know what to do with the $4^{\text{th}}$ power, so I ignore it, although I know it's wrong.. $$\implies x^2+y^2+x-iy=x^2+y^2$$ $$\implies x=iy$$ $$\text{or, } y=-xi$$Now, this is the equation of a straight line, and therefore the correct option is $D$ (collinear).

> Firstly, am I correct ?

> Secondly, if I am, then what's the use of the fourth power ? If I am not, what is the correct solution to this problem and where is my mistake ?

Thank You so much for your help.. :)

Comment: Perhaps $w^4=1 \iff w = \pm 1\text{ or } \pm i$ would help.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful! $$
x = -yi
$$
means $x=y=0$ because $x$ and $y$ have to be real numbers. But $z=0$ is not a solution to $\left(1+\frac1z\right)^4 = 1$. (note that when you were arriving at this solution, you would've had at one point $0/0$. Your algebraic manipulations appear to be correct, but all in vain if the denominator is $0$). This means that there is no solution to $$
\left(\frac{x^2+y^2 + x - i y}{x^2+y^2}\right) = 1
$$
so the 4th power is relevant!

Just like with square roots, fourth roots in $\mathbb{C}$ are not unique. Every complex number has four fourth roots. For $1$, you can easily check that they are $1$, $-1$, $i$, and $-i$. Can you solve it from there?

Comment: Thanks! You are very much right there.. But I couldn't solve that big fourth power.. Can you please give me some hints on how to solve complex $4^{\text{th}}$ powers ?

Comment: If you take a fourth root, you get $\frac{x^2+y^2+x-iy}{x^2+y^2} = \sqrt[4]{1}$. Since there's four different possible values for $\sqrt[4]{1}$, you have four possible equations to solve.

Comment: Thank you so much.. I will try..

Comment: I tried it! I get the four solutions of $(x,y)$ as $$(0,0),(-\frac{1}2,0),(-\frac{1}2,-\frac{1}2),(-\frac{1}2,\frac{1}2)$$ Am I correct ? But, if I graph these points, I don't seem to arrive at any of the options as given in the question.. If I exclude $(-\frac{1}2,0)$, then the other three form a right angled triangle..

Comment: Almost! Read the first part of my answer about the point $(0,0)$ - Does this point actually solve the equation?

Comment: Oh yes!! Thank You so much.. 

Answer (score 0):

Let $w=1+\frac{1}z $ then

$$w^4=1 \implies w_i=e^{ik\frac{\pi}{2}} \quad k=0,1,2,3$$

then

$$w=1+\frac{1}z \implies z=\frac1{w-1}=\frac{\bar w-1}{|w-1|^2}$$

that is

- $z_1=-\frac{1+i}{2}$
- $z_2=-\frac{1}{2}$
- $z_3=-\frac{1-i}{2}$